# How Symfony did its command alias?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, alias

Apologies my french english ...

I would like to create an alias in Windows XP cmd, like Symfony.

This code works perfectly, but resets every system boot :

```
doskey kCLI= php C:\wamp\www\KinkamaCLI\KinkamaCLI.php
```

I tryed to put a .bat in "start" folder, but I think it's not beautifull, and I feel it doesn't work, because I can't see the generate batch file :

```
echo doskey kCLI= php C:\wamp\www\KinkamaCLI\KinkamaCLI.php >> C:\Documents and Settings\sartois\Menu Démarrer\Programmes\Démarrage\kCLI.bat
```

I would to create a permanent alias. Enter :

```
kCLI my-command-here
```

And not :

```
php C:\wamp\www\KinkamaCLI\KinkamaCLI.php my-command-here
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how symfony proceed, but may be you should check your %PATH% environment variable and add this new path. Check http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519 on how to modify this variable.

Comment: Thanks,

I progress. I create a script installer, .bat, and I would like to know how to call doskey in it.

Because that work in direct input :

doskey kCLI= php C:\wamp\www\KinkamaCLI\KinkamaCLI.php

then

doskey /macros >> "C:\Documents and Settings\%login%\Menu Démarrer\Programmes\Démarrage\kCLI.bat"

But when I put that in the .bat, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

cmd.exe has support for running a list of commands at startup, add your doskey command to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` (Note that it is possible to start cmd.exe with /D to skip the autorun entry. I have also seen problems with doskey.exe crashing in 3rd party apps when autorun entry is parsed)